# MySQL: Problems with FLOAT

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-types

I made a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vehicles (
    vehicleid INT(3),
    vehiclex FLOAT(6,6),
    vehicley FLOAT(6,6),
    vehiclez FLOAT(6,6),
    vehicleaw FLOAT(6,6),
    vehiclecolor1 INT(2),
    vehiclecolor2 INT(2)
)
```

Now when I'm trying to insert this:

```
INSERT INTO vehicles (vehicleid,vehiclex,vehicley,vehiclez,vehicleaw,vehiclecolor1,vehiclecolor2)
VALUES(411,1786.9001,-1892.1359,13.4903,14.0000,0,0)
```

First of all, now errors, no warnings :)

I'm getting a invalid row in SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `vehicles` ORDER BY `vehicles`.`vehiclez` ASC LIMIT 0, 30 ;
```

**result**
Rows: 1

> vehicleid vehiclex    vehicley    vehiclez    vehicleaw   vehiclecolor1   vehiclecolor2
>   411   0.999999    -0.999999   0.999999    0.999999    0   0

So, What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to [FLOAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html) is the total number of digits, not the number of digits that can occur before the decimal point.

In your current code, the total number of digits is the same as the number of digits that can occur after the decimal point, so the numbers stored cannot be greater than `0.999999` (or less than `-0.999999`).

Try something like `FLOAT(12, 6)`.